# Git diff doesn't work after git stash pop

Tags: git, qt-creator, git-stash

After `git stash pop`, there were some conflicts, things like:

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
int foo = 5;
=======
int foo = 6;
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

I resolved them in the code, but now I can't preview my changes before committing them. All I get is this, and I know there are changes:

```
diff --cc mainwindow.cpp
index 24dc025,2c44ad8..0000000
--- a/mainwindow.cpp
+++ b/mainwindow.cpp
```

How do I force git diff to compare my current source to the last commit?

Comment: It gives only `* Unmerged path mainwindow.cpp`.

Comment: what is the output of `git status --short`?

Comment: It gives `UU mainwindow.cpp`.

Comment: Based on my similar experience, I suspect that git is diffing against the stashed code rather than the most recent commit.  But I'm not yet enough of an expert on this to give a full answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `pop` resulted in a merge conflict. In order to resolve it, you need to edit the file (which you already did) and then call `git add mainwindow.cpp` to tell git, that you have resolved the conflict.

If you want to preview your changes, you can do so with `git diff --cached`. This is because `git add` already added your changes to the index.

Comment: The curious thing is that if you now execute:
    `git stash`
then
    `git stash pop`

a conventional git diff will now work as expected. Perhaps I'm wrong to expect a `git stash pop` to be (in effect) the inverse function of `git stash`, bringing you back to an identical state. That isn't the case here.